# Clean up branch's commit history by omitting commits which are now on master

Tags: git, github

I have a feature branch, and I want to clean up its commit history so it's easier to review. Many of the old commits are actually from other branches which have since been squash-merged into master.

I'd like to somehow delete all of those commits which have now been (squash-)included in master, and rebase(?) to the current master branch. (The goal is just cleaning up the history for review, so it doesn't need to actually involve "deleting" or "rebasing" as long as it achieves this goal.)

There are many old commits and it would take a long time to go through them individually, so I'm looking for an automatic method if possible. (I'd guess it's possible somehow to see if a commit's changes are already present in master, and to then ignore it if so, right?)

I looked through the commands given in `git -h` and `git rebase -h`, but I wasn't sure which, if any, would accomplish this; I'm a little hesitant to play around without knowing what I'm doing here, since I don't want to mess up my working directory too badly.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: "I'm a little hesitant to play around without knowing what I'm doing here": Don't be hesitant. Just make a copy of the repository and go wild. Completely destroy it? Just delete it and make a new copy. Do this when following any instructions posted here if you don't completely understand them.

Comment: That said, you may just be looking for `git checkout <my-branch>; git rebase master`, although if the history has been diverged for a while you're probably going to need to resolve some conflicts.

Comment: @larsks hmm, okay, I'll give a straightforward rebase a shot!

Comment: @larsks it looks like I might have to resolve 53 rounds of merge conflicts if I go that way, unfortunately...and git doesn't seem to know how to deal with squash-merges and/or commits which are later undone by other commits  Is there a better way?

Comment: Hard to say without being able to work with the actual repository. Maybe someone else will have a better idea.

Comment: @larsks (and anyone else) Hmm...can "merge strategies" maybe help here? something that lets me say "always prefer the current (final) state over a different state"? Because ultimately, I don't want to change anything—I just want to change the history.

Comment: @thorimur: how did the squash merges occur ? by merging pull requests in github ?

Comment: @LeGEC The repository I'm contributing to uses squash merges to merge feature branches—kind of. It actually uses [bors](https://github.com/bors-ng/bors-ng) to merge contributions, which I think actually makes a copy of the branch then merges it, or something like that.

Comment: @thorimur: can you confirm that you can see `refs/pull/[id]/head` and `refs/pull/[id]/merge` references is `git ls-remote origin` ? this could be a start to *script* your way around those squash merges

Comment: @LeGEC I can indeed see those! but...what do they all mean? scripting would be nice, if I had some idea how to start...!

Comment: "Many of the old commits are actually from other branches which have since been squash-merged into master." Why are all of those commits on your feature branch, and how were they brought in? (Cherry-pick, merge, etc.)

Comment: @TTT They were brought in because when I created this branch, I wanted to use another (then-unmerged) feature branch as the source branch, which in turn was sourced on some other feature branch. Now those old feature branches have been squash-merged to master, but I'm left with their old (unsquashed) commits on my branch. (well, bors-merged to master, which means the branch was copied then deleted, I think.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the first half of the answer is isolating the "leftovers" which haven't been merged in yet. This can be done a few different ways, but one of the simplest is to just test the merge:

```
git fetch

# create a temp branch for testing the merge
git switch -c test-merge origin/master --no-track # create a branch name test-merge
# OR, if you know you will throw this away, then don't bother with a branch
git switch --detach origin/master # checkout master but detached

# Merge in the feature branch
git merge my-feature-branch
# OR, if you want to squash all of the changes on the feature branch into a single commit
git merge --squash my-feature-branch # make a single commit with all changes
# resolve conflicts if necessary, and commit

git diff @~1 @ # this is what would actually change if you PR my-feature-branch into master
```

By inspecting the diff (or what's in the squashed commit), you may be able to decide how important it is to keep all of the commits that led to these changes, or if you can just keep the squashed commit. If you're OK with the squashed commit, then simply push out your branch and create the PR.

If you wish to try to rewrite the history of the feature branch to keep the still relevant commits in the repo, at least now you have an end state to try to reach.

**Side Note:** although having history is nice, occasionally I've found myself in situations where I wish to rebase so I can remove some commits, but there are so many conflicts on my branch that rebasing would not be a good option. Sometimes in this position I'll make sure to create the PR first, then do the squash merge and force push, with the understanding that if I ever want to see the history prior to the squash merge, I can just go look at the PR history in the UI tool.

Comment: This seems reasonable, thanks for the advice! :) Starting fresh-ish like this a good idea. What would make this really viable, though, would be being able to do the following: 1) start with master 2) load all of the changes onto my working tree(?)—so, the "final" state of the feature branch, but not committed yet 3) stage changes bit by bit and make new, clean commits for different parts. (I'm working in VS code, so the UI there might be helpful for the last bit, somehow, I'm thinking...)

Is (2) what the `git merge --squash ...` will do? Or does the merge automatically include a commit?

Comment: Yup, indeed that is what `git merge --squash ...` will do. This worked really well, thanks. :)

Comment: @thorimur Just FYI, some git commands that create a commit, such as `cherry-pick`, `revert`, and `merge`, have an option called `--no-commit` which will pause right before creating the commit leaving the changes staged. Then you can do as you wish by unstaging certain files, commit, restage the next set, commit, etc. `merge --squash` actually has `--no-commit` built in.

Comment: @thorimur Side note, even if you didn't know about `--no-commit` and you already made the commit, you can still `git reset --mixed @~1` (btw `@` == `HEAD`) which will go back to the previous commit but leave all the changes as pending and unstaged. If you use `git reset --soft @~1` it's the same but with all the changes already staged. `reset --mixed` is the default if you don't specify.